# Execute Script after append element from ajax callback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, razor

From an ajax call i get a div and a script that populate the div with another ajax call.
the problem is that when the script is run it can't find the div.

this is the razor code :

```
@model int

@{
    var id = string.Format("riga_{0}", Model);
}
<div id="@id">
    wait please...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#" + "@id").load("/RigaMovimento/Details/@Model");
</script>
```

that generate this :

```
<div id="riga_79">
    wait please...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#" + "riga_79").load("/RigaMovimento/Details/79");
</script>
```

**ANSWER**

is not beautifull, but works :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", new { movimentoId = Model.MovimentoId }, new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter, UpdateTargetId = "righe", OnSuccess = "run_after" }))
{
    <input type="submit" value="New" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var run_after;
</script>
```

the create view :

```
@model int

@{
    var id = string.Format("riga_{0}", Model);
}

<div id="@id">
    wait please...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    run_after = function () {
        $('#' + '@id').load(
            "/RigaMovimento/Details/@Model", 
            null, 
            function() { $('#' + '@id').fadeIn('slow'); } );
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still struggling with this, I thought of a neat solution. Suppose you are making a jQuery ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'fragment.html',
  success: function(html) {
    $('body').append(html);
  }
});
```

Suppose `fragment.html` looks like this:

```
<div class="fillme">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript>
  $('.fillme').text('I am filled.');
</script>
```

Then the desired state of `div.fillme` is:

```
<div class="fillme">
  I am filled.
</div>
```

But of course it won't happen because the div and the script are being appended simultaneously, and therefore `div.fillme` does not exist at the time of script execution. The problem, then, can be solved by appending script *after* appending the div. Note that the following line of code:

```
var $html = $(html);
```

will put the list

```
[<div class="fillme"></div>, <script type="text/javascript">...</script>]
```

into the `$html` variable. These are fully functional DOM fragments that have not yet been appended to the DOM. Most importantly, the script has not yet executed; it will when we append it. We will make sure to append it after appending the div. Here is some generic code that does that:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'fragment.html',
  success: function(html) {
    var $html = $(html);
    var nonscripts = $html.filter(function() { return !$(this).is('script'); });
    var scripts = $html.filter(function() { return !$(this).is('script'); });
    $('body').append(nonscripts).append(scripts);
  }
});
```

And that's all, folks.

**Edit:** Here is an even more generic solution that simply makes use of the fact that elements in the `$html` variable are listed in the order they appear in in the HTML fragment:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'fragment.html',
  success: function(html) {
    $(html).each(function(i, element) {
      $('body').append(element);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        /* code */
    });
</script>
```

Comment: the function is executed before adding the div. this means that it can't find the div

Comment: use jQuery ready statement "$(function() {", so the script will be executed after generating html. If the div is loaded via DOM see my other answer, can't figure it out with your code.
`<div id="riga_79">
    wait please...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#" + "riga_79").load("/RigaMovimento/Details/79");
    });
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

If the div is in the DOM, jQuery can't find it in HTML.
If you load the script on an event, you can use jQuery.live like this

```
$( 'element' ).live( 'click', function(){
     $("#" + "riga_79").load("/RigaMovimento/Details/79");
});
```

maybe this could work (didn't test it)

```
$( 'body' ).live( 'load', function() {
    $("#" + "riga_79").load("/RigaMovimento/Details/79");
});
```

otherwise use the [livequery plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs) like this:

```
$("#" + "riga_79").livequery(function(){
     $(this).load("/RigaMovimento/Details/79");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$(--selector--).load method has an additional callback parameter

http://api.jquery.com/load/

This is a function which is called once your AJAX response is completed.
However script part which you return in AJAX response is never evaluated by default.

You have to apply a little trick here. Please find an Update javascript module below which has a public method "evaluate". This method takes your script from AJAX response and evaluates it.

```
var Updater = function ()
{
    var module = {};

    function doEvaluation(response)
    {
        var elem = document.createElement('div');
        elem.innerHTML = response;
        $(elem).find('script').each(
            function ()
            {
                if (this.src)
                {
                    $('body').append(this);
                }
                else
                {
                    var content = $(this).html();
                    eval(content);
                }
            });
    }

    module.evaluate = function (response, status)
    {
        if (status == "success")
        {
            doEvaluation(response);
        }
    }
    return module;
} ();
```

You can even attach a completely new javascript with it (if statement inside doEvaluation method). So what you need to do is add the module above so that it resides on your page. Secondly you have to modify your first AJAX call (which returns a PartialResult which is broken now) to something similar to this:

```
$('--selector--').load('--url--', Updater.evaluate);
```

or

```
$.get('--url--', function(data, status, xhr) 
{
    /* other logic */
    Updater.evaluate(data, status);
});
```

and you are done. Please notice that updater below works only with jQuery AJAX calls. IF you are using MicrosoftAjax or MicrosoftMvcAjax its another story.